# How to convert a column from a table in a dataset to a string separated by commas in C#?

Tags: c#, database, windows-forms-designer, ms-access-2016

I am making an windows form application in c#, it has to be able to send an email to all the recipient ids that are in a table in an Access Database.

I already understand how to send the mails and even successfully made tests, but I don't understand how to convert column the has all de email ids to a comma separated string.

I am also kinda confused if this code goes inside the forms code or somewhere else.

I already tried using foreach loops and for some reason they have errors saying that i cannot use them.

I have also read a bit of linq but i could not understand where to even implement such code in my program.

Here is the code for the email sending button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpserver = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("latinaultimatesite@gmail.com");

        mail.To.Add("diomidiov@gmail.com,ninjaboy.abel@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Que xopa";
        mail.Body = "probando 1 2 3";

        smtpserver.Port = 587;
        smtpserver.Credentials = new 
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("latinaultimatesite@gmail.com","proyectofinal69lus");
        smtpserver.EnableSsl = true;

        smtpserver.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

For now I have achieved sending mail to the accounts seen in the code, so that works, what I need is the accounts in the database to be in a separated comma string format so I can use them in this button.

Comment: loop through the rows and using string concatenation (or a string builder) to append each row form the database along with a comma. Ensure the comma at the end is removed upon finishing the loop.

Comment: could you make a simple example to see how it would look like?

Comment: it would be hard to as you have not shown in the code supplied how you have gained access to the rows in the column. Are they part of a `OledbDataReader` or a `DataSet` Also, an example of your For Each would help us help you better.

Comment: Please formulate your question more clear and concentrate on the main problem. You ask about a database problem in your title, but your question and sample code concentrate mostly about email sending.

Comment: The table i need to access is part of a dataset, and im sorry for the bad question, im changing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear why you would not simply query the database for this info. However, if you already have the `DataTable` then, as others have pointed out, you will need to loop through the `DataTable.Rows` collection and grab the email address cell from that row, add a comma, then continue this for all the rows in the table. A `StringBuilder` may be helpful for building this comma delimited email string. It may look something like below…

```
private string GetEmailAddress(DataTable dt) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    sb.Append(dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString());
    if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
      sb.Append(",");
  }
  sb.AppendLine();
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, im gonna try to implement it. but for now this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you should try to split that string and then add every email I'd to 'To' clause.

One example is illustrated here:-

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/sending-email-to-multiple-recipeint-using-Asp-Net/

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The example you have provided doesn't explain main problem. How to extract data from the database and build the list of the To recipients from that data.

Comment: Exactly, steve that is what i wanna know, i dont understand how to build the list.